# Find all numeric values in JSON and replace them enclosed in quotes

Tags: php, json, regex

```
[{
  "SomeValue1": 16237351025487570926,
  "SomeValue2": "value2",
  "SomeValue3": "value3"
 }, {
  "SomeValue1": 16237351025487570926,
  "SomeValue2": "value2",
  "SomeValue3": "value3"
}]
```

I need to search and replace SomeValue1 with same value but wrapped in quotes (shown bellow).

```
[{
  "SomeValue1": "16237351025487570926",
  "SomeValue2": "value2",
  "SomeValue3": "value3"
 }, {
  "SomeValue1": "16237351025487570926",
  "SomeValue2": "value2",
  "SomeValue3": "value3"
}]
```

I need to have php regex (JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is somethink else in this case) .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use something like this

```
\s(\d+),
```

and then replace with

```
"$1"
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/QqDQh8/1)

Comment: Should be interesting if the json contains numeric indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is actually *not* something else:

```
$json = '[{
  "SomeValue1": 16237351025487570926
 }, {
  "SomeValue1": 16237351025487570926
}]';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["SomeValue1"] => float(1.6237351025488E+19)
  }
  [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["SomeValue1"] => float(1.6237351025488E+19)
  }
}

array(2) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["SomeValue1"] => string(20) "16237351025487570926"
  }
  [1]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["SomeValue1"] => string(20) "16237351025487570926"
  }
}
```

So basically, you can just do:

```
echo json_encode(json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

This only works for a large enough integer that it is actually a float, if you want to convert every integer just loop over the array:

```
foreach($arr = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING) as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $k => $v){
    if(gettype($v) == 'integer'){
      $arr[$key][$k] = (string) $v;
    }
  }
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Actually there is. The problem is php json extension modul because I guess there's a bug in json_version 1.3.6. and JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is ignored.